# Echo in front of a periodic building

Tags: acoustics

[image: Riser vs tread]

Hello,
I recently found out that walking in front of a building leads to a strange echo (and so does clapping). The noticeable thing is that the facade of the building looks like a flipped staircase (see the rectangle on the image)

If we consider it as a real staircase, the riser ("r") and the tread ("t") do not have the same dimensions.

When we see the building under a certain angle (see the point of view of source 1, in red), we clearly see a staircase whose dimensions are r = 40 cm and t = 10 cm (higher than deep). We cannot hear anything except the clap when walking from left to right and clapping.

At the opposite position (see the point of view of source 2, in blue), the dimensions are inverted (r = 10 cm, t = 40 cm) and the steps are deeper than high. This time, the effect appears and we can hear a very distinct frequency when walking from right to left and clapping.

Is there anything that explains this difference of contribution between the tread and the riser of the steps? What are your thoughts on the echo appearing only for position 2 and walking to the left?

Thanks by advance if you can help me understand this strange phenomenon !

Comment: This is a rather complicated question you ask. It boils down to the reflection of sound from the facade and the psychoacoustics of perceiving a delayed sound as an echo. Although echo perception does not have such as strong frequency dependence as the reflection of sound, both phenomena are frequency-dependent. Since you have a rather complicated structure, and you don’t provide any information about the source other than the clap (which could be assumed to be “full spectrum” as a first approximation) all we can assume is that there are some frequencies that will be reflected... (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) or scattered since you have a “comb-like” structure in such a way as to be delayed by some “appropriate” time length that will be perceived as an echo. The orientation of the structure **does** play a role here in the spatial/polar pattern of the reflected sound energy but it is not easy to eyeball it (or at least I cannot do it). I believe the best way to get a better understanding would be to model the two structures and solve them with some numerical method (FEM, BEM, FDTD, etc.). Although this is not a trivial task, I believe it could shed some light on the problem. (cont.)

Comment: Finally, you’d have to analyse the results and either take them through a psychoacoustics model or assume a constant (frequency-independent) duration threshold for the perception of echo and see whether any of the structures achieves that and for which frequencies.